# How to use live method with zclip plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use live method with this -> http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Edit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a#copy-description').zclip({
path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
copy:$('p#description').text()
});
```

i need to use live method cuz `a#copy-description` will be generate via javascript.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? Do you have any code to provide? You should probably share what you have first and ask a question if you get stuck on it, you'll find people will be more than happy to help then.

Answer (score 1):

try to use [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) instead of live. That way you'll be able to bind zclip when it appears in the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('a#copy-description').livequery(function(){
     $(this).zclip({ path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf', copy:$('p#description').text();
  });
});
```